# Trouble with MySQL FULLTEXT indexes

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have been entering the following SQL statement, but it has not been turning up any results and I cannot figure out why. The error on phpMyAdmin reads:

```
#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(subj_name, course_name, content_type) AGAINST('math, statistics, 
test') AS score from table1 WHERE MATCH(subj_name, course_name, content_type) 
AGAINST('math, statistics, test') ORDER BY score desc;
```

And this is how I made my index:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD FULLTEXT(subj_name, course_name, content_type);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try to add

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD FULLTEXT fulltext_index(subj_name, course_name, content_type);
```